# Android Inapp billing example

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I'm trying to run the Android Inapp Billing Example but have apparently done something wrong since it doesn't work as intended.

My best clue about what is wrong is that when the market billing pop-up show the title is "Sample application title by Sample Merchant" and since I don't find that text anywhere neither in the code or in the Developer Console I think that my application is attempting to connect to someone else account for payment.

Any ideas what is wrong, I have copied in my "key" into the application as instructed in the description.

Thanks in advance
Roland

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah,

You're running your app compiled from eclipse so it's being signed with your development key.

You need to sign it with a release key and you need to be sure that in the Security.java file you've set the base64EncodedPublicKey to your android market public key (available under the Edit Profile link in the android market app).

So steps are:

1. Make sure you put your public key into the Security.java file
2. Export a release build of your application
3. Run adb install YOURAPKNAME to put your application on the phone

Then you will see the sample app pop up listing your application title and you as the merchant + you will be able to make real purchases.

Comment: Still no success. 
1) I checked my merchant account to verify that I had copied the right code
2) I used the "export signed application package"-function to generate a apk-file. 
3) I ran adb install. 

I still get the "Sample Mercant" message.

Comment: Solved it. I missunderstood the demands on the "draft"-application. It wasn't enough that it was uploaded. It also needed of other properties, like pictures etc. When I uploaded sample-images and made sure all other properties was set, the application started to work as supposed.